# beginner on mono for osx 10.9.2

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I'm a complete beginner to mono & c#. I have source code for this public domain windows app that looks like is written in c#. Is it true I can use mono to compile it for mac? Or does mono allow me to run the windows .exe directly on mac? It's been decades since I compiled anything so if someone can point me to where I should start that would be great. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it true I can use mono to compile it for mac?

Yes.

> Or does mono allow me to run the windows .exe directly on mac?

If that .exe is managed (compiled with .NET) and doesn't have unmanaged dependencies, yes too.

> It's been decades since I compiled anything so if someone can point me to where I should start that would be great.

Download Xamarin Studio, start coding.